# Is there any way to delete a dynamically allocated array in another function?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am learning pointers in C++. This is the exercise given by my teacher:

```
6. Duplicate a given array.
int* copyArray(int* arr, int n)
```

My function:

```
int* copyArray(int* arr, int n)
{
    int* copy = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        copy[i] = arr[i];
    return copy; 

}
```

My main function:

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = { -2, -3, 4, -1, -2, 1, 5, -3 };
    int* copyPtr = new int[8];
    copyPtr = copyArray(a, 8);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        cout << copyPtr[i] << " "; 
    delete[] copyPtr;
}
```

Is there any way that I can delete *copy* array from the main function? I understand the use of smart pointers but I cant use it in this case because of the prototype given by my teacher.

Comment: Exactly as you are doing now? Only that you are leaking the first allocation...

Comment: You already are `delete` ing `copyPtr` - not sure what you are asking about?

Comment: `copyPtr` and `copy` both are pointing to the same memory address. So `delete[] copyPtr` is the same as `delete[] copy`.

Comment: the question is unclear, because you are already deleting the copied array `copyPtr`.

Comment: All you need to do is remove `= new int[8]` from `main`. You don't seem to use that allocation for anything.

Comment: `int* copyPtr = new int[8]; copyPtr = copyArray(a, 8);` leaks memory in two lines of code. This isn't Java/C# . You do not need to (and do not *want* to) `new` everything under the sun. That should be `int* copyPtr = copyArray(a, 8);` . Then, sometime down the road, you'll eventually learn how `std::vector` makes things like this irrelevant.

Comment: If you compare your solution with `std::memcpy()`, you will notice a significant difference: `std::memcpy()` gets a pointer to destination, a pointer to source, and a length. Thus, the `std::memcpy()` is responsible for copying only but not for the allocation. I.e. it can be used to copy any array regardless how the destination buffer is allocated. That's not possible with your function. It always allocates with `new int[]` and makes the caller responsible to `delete[]` that. Usually, `new[]` and `delete[]` should be kept on the same level (for easier S/W maintenance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that you are confused by the usual imprecision when we say "delete a pointer". More correct would be to say `delete[] x` deletes the array that `x` points to.

In `main` you do

```
copyPtr = copyArray(a, 8);
```

Now `copyPtr` does point to the copy of the array. When you write

```
delete[] copyPtr;
```

You delete the copy of the array.

What you miss is to delete the initial array you created via `int* copyPtr = new int[8];` and because you lost any pointer to it you cannot delete it anymore. You could keep the pointer to that initial array and delete it as well. Though, there is no point in allocating an array just to throw it away and create a new array inside the function. Change your code to

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = { -2, -3, 4, -1, -2, 1, 5, -3 };
    int* copyPtr = copyArray(a, 8);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        cout << copyPtr[i] << " "; 
    delete[] copyPtr;
}
```

PS:

> I understand the use of smart pointers but I cant use it in this case because of the prototype given by my teacher.

Your conclusion is not right. Smartpointers can interoperate with raw pointers quite well. You just need to take care with ownership. `int* arr` is passed as raw pointer. Thats completely fine, because the function does not participate in ownership of that array. It merely reads its values. Raw pointers are for non-owning pointers. If you want to take ownership of the returned pointer you can use a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`:

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = { -2, -3, 4, -1, -2, 1, 5, -3 };
    auto copy = std::unique_ptr<int[]>(copyArray(a,8));

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) std::cout << copy[i] << " "; 
    // no delete !!! the unique_ptr does that for you
}
```